# App crashes during unsuccessful login attempt in Android

Tags: android, authentication, android-asynctask, http-post

First of all, I'm a newcomer to android development. I'm trying to develop an app that will login into a specific site and parse a XML file as a response from the site. I've written the code and its working only in successful login but the app crashes when login in unsuccessful (incorrect username/password). I also used AsyncTask but still no luck. Check the code for more info,

```
@Override
    public void onClick(View view) {
        if (view == ok) {
            new AttemptLogin().execute();
        }
    }

class AttemptLogin extends AsyncTask<String, String, String> {

        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute() {
            super.onPreExecute();
            pDialog = new ProgressDialog(MainActivity.this);
            pDialog.setMessage("Attempting Login...");
            pDialog.setIndeterminate(false);
            pDialog.setCancelable(true);
            pDialog.show();
        }

        @Override
        protected String doInBackground(String... arg0) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            // Create a new HttpClient and Post Header
            HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();

            HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost(
                    "http://...");

            try {
                // Add user name, password & pin
                String action = "login";

                EditText uname = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.etUsername);
                String username = uname.getText().toString();

                EditText pword = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.etPassword);
                String password = pword.getText().toString();

                EditText pcode = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.etPin);
                String pin = pcode.getText().toString();

                List<NameValuePair> nameValuePairs = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>(
                        4);
                nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("action", action));
                nameValuePairs
                        .add(new BasicNameValuePair("username", username));
                nameValuePairs
                        .add(new BasicNameValuePair("password", password));
                nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("pin", pin));
                httppost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(nameValuePairs));

                // Execute HTTP Post Request
                HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httppost);

                responseXML = httpclient.execute(httppost,
                        new BasicResponseHandler());
                // passing xml data to dom parser 
                dom_parser();

            } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            return null;
        }

        protected void onPostExecute(String file_url) {
            // dismiss the dialog once executed
            pDialog.dismiss();
            if (ack.equals("SUCCESS")) {

                Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, msg, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

                Intent as = new Intent(MainActivity.this, AccountSummary.class);
                // add user data
                SharedPreferences sp = PreferenceManager
                        .getDefaultSharedPreferences(MainActivity.this);
                Editor edit = sp.edit();
                edit.putString("username", username);
                edit.putString("ewallpoints", ewallpoints);
                edit.putString("name", name);
                edit.commit();

                startActivity(as);
                as.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
                finish();


            }

            else {
                //setting an error message in the TextBox
                response_xml.setText("Incorrect Login!");

            }

        }
    }
} 


           public void dom_parser() {
    try {

        // File stocks = new File(responseXML);
        DocumentBuilderFactory dbFactory = DocumentBuilderFactory
                .newInstance();
        DocumentBuilder dBuilder = dbFactory.newDocumentBuilder();
        Document doc = dBuilder.parse(new InputSource(new StringReader(
                responseXML)));
        doc.getDocumentElement().normalize();

        NodeList nodes = doc.getElementsByTagName("member");

        for (int i = 0; i < nodes.getLength(); i++) {
            Node node = nodes.item(i);

            if (node.getNodeType() == Node.ELEMENT_NODE) {
                Element element = (Element) node;

                ack = ((getValue("ack", element)));
                id = ((getValue("id", element)));
                username = ((getValue("username", element)));
                name = ((getValue("name", element)));
                ewallpoints = ((getValue("ewallpoints", element)));
                msg = ((getValue("msg", element)));
            }
        }
    } catch (Exception ex) {
        ex.printStackTrace();
        response_xml.setText("error!");
    }

}

private static String getValue(String tag, Element element) {
    NodeList nodes = element.getElementsByTagName(tag).item(0)
            .getChildNodes();
    Node node = (Node) nodes.item(0);
    return node.getNodeValue();
}
```

Here 'ack' is the success/failure message which was parsed from the xml output!

```
<login>
<member>
<id/>
<username/>
<name/>
<ewallpoints/>
<ack>FAILED</ack>
<msg>Wrong Username and Password</msg>
</member>
</login>
```

here is the logcat output,

```
06-18 11:13:18.216: I/ActivityManager(294): Start proc com.p2r.mobifin for activity com.p2r.mobifin/.MainActivity: pid=17984 uid=10050 gids={50050, 3003, 1028}
06-18 11:13:18.526: E/SurfaceFlinger(36): ro.sf.lcd_density must be defined as a build property
06-18 11:13:18.656: E/Trace(17984): error opening trace file: No such file or directory (2)
06-18 11:13:19.406: D/dalvikvm(17984): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 57K, 7% free 2499K/2676K, paused 56ms, total 58ms
06-18 11:13:19.436: I/dalvikvm-heap(17984): Grow heap (frag case) to 5.802MB for 3404596-byte allocation
06-18 11:13:19.546: D/dalvikvm(17984): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 2K, 4% free 5821K/6004K, paused 109ms, total 109ms
06-18 11:13:19.596: D/dalvikvm(17984): GC_CONCURRENT freed <1K, 4% free 5821K/6004K, paused 4ms+17ms, total 55ms
06-18 11:13:19.766: E/ActivityThread(434): Failed to find provider info for com.android.inputmethod.latin.dictionarypack
06-18 11:13:19.766: E/BinaryDictionaryGetter(434): Could not find a dictionary pack
06-18 11:13:19.906: E/SurfaceFlinger(36): ro.sf.lcd_density must be defined as a build property
06-18 11:13:20.016: D/gralloc_goldfish(17984): Emulator without GPU emulation detected.
06-18 11:13:20.105: I/ActivityManager(294): Displayed com.p2r.mobifin/.MainActivity: +1s947ms
06-18 11:13:25.146: E/SurfaceFlinger(36): ro.sf.lcd_density must be defined as a build property
06-18 11:13:26.866: E/SurfaceFlinger(36): ro.sf.lcd_density must be defined as a build property
06-18 11:13:27.996: D/dalvikvm(17984): GC_CONCURRENT freed 96K, 4% free 6749K/6968K, paused 79ms+173ms, total 394ms
06-18 11:13:27.996: I/Choreographer(17984): Skipped 100 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
06-18 11:13:28.396: I/Choreographer(17984): Skipped 37 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
06-18 11:13:28.646: I/Choreographer(17984): Skipped 34 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
06-18 11:13:29.306: I/Choreographer(17984): Skipped 33 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
06-18 11:13:29.436: I/Choreographer(17984): Skipped 34 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
06-18 11:13:29.666: I/Choreographer(17984): Skipped 30 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
06-18 11:13:29.776: W/SingleClientConnManager(17984): Invalid use of SingleClientConnManager: connection still allocated.
06-18 11:13:29.776: W/SingleClientConnManager(17984): Make sure to release the connection before allocating another one.
06-18 11:13:30.145: I/Choreographer(17984): Skipped 32 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
06-18 11:13:30.416: I/Choreographer(17984): Skipped 37 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
06-18 11:13:30.826: W/System.err(17984): java.lang.NullPointerException
06-18 11:13:30.856: W/System.err(17984):    at com.p2r.mobifin.MainActivity.getValue(MainActivity.java:104)
06-18 11:13:30.856: W/System.err(17984):    at com.p2r.mobifin.MainActivity.dom_parser(MainActivity.java:86)
06-18 11:13:30.856: W/System.err(17984):    at com.p2r.mobifin.MainActivity$AttemptLogin.doInBackground(MainActivity.java:165)
06-18 11:13:30.856: W/System.err(17984):    at com.p2r.mobifin.MainActivity$AttemptLogin.doInBackground(MainActivity.java:1)
06-18 11:13:30.856: W/System.err(17984):    at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:287)
06-18 11:13:30.856: W/System.err(17984):    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:234)
06-18 11:13:30.856: W/System.err(17984):    at android.os.AsyncTask$SerialExecutor$1.run(AsyncTask.java:230)
06-18 11:13:30.856: W/System.err(17984):    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1080)
06-18 11:13:30.866: W/System.err(17984):    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:573)
06-18 11:13:30.866: W/System.err(17984):    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:856)
06-18 11:13:30.916: W/dalvikvm(17984): threadid=13: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x40a71930)
06-18 11:13:31.066: E/AndroidRuntime(17984): FATAL EXCEPTION: AsyncTask #3
06-18 11:13:31.066: E/AndroidRuntime(17984): java.lang.RuntimeException: An error occured while executing doInBackground()
06-18 11:13:31.066: E/AndroidRuntime(17984):    at android.os.AsyncTask$3.done(AsyncTask.java:299)
06-18 11:13:31.066: E/AndroidRuntime(17984):    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.finishCompletion(FutureTask.java:352)
06-18 11:13:31.066: E/AndroidRuntime(17984):    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.setException(FutureTask.java:219)
06-18 11:13:31.066: E/AndroidRuntime(17984):    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:239)
06-18 11:13:31.066: E/AndroidRuntime(17984):    at android.os.AsyncTask$SerialExecutor$1.run(AsyncTask.java:230)
06-18 11:13:31.066: E/AndroidRuntime(17984):    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1080)
06-18 11:13:31.066: E/AndroidRuntime(17984):    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:573)
06-18 11:13:31.066: E/AndroidRuntime(17984):    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:856)
06-18 11:13:31.066: E/AndroidRuntime(17984): Caused by: android.view.ViewRootImpl$CalledFromWrongThreadException: Only the original thread that created a view hierarchy can touch its views.
06-18 11:13:31.066: E/AndroidRuntime(17984):    at android.view.ViewRootImpl.checkThread(ViewRootImpl.java:4746)
06-18 11:13:31.066: E/AndroidRuntime(17984):    at android.view.ViewRootImpl.requestLayout(ViewRootImpl.java:823)
06-18 11:13:31.066: E/AndroidRuntime(17984):    at android.view.View.requestLayout(View.java:15473)
06-18 11:13:31.066: E/AndroidRuntime(17984):    at android.view.View.requestLayout(View.java:15473)
06-18 11:13:31.066: E/AndroidRuntime(17984):    at android.view.View.requestLayout(View.java:15473)
06-18 11:13:31.066: E/AndroidRuntime(17984):    at android.view.View.requestLayout(View.java:15473)
06-18 11:13:31.066: E/AndroidRuntime(17984):    at android.widget.RelativeLayout.requestLayout(RelativeLayout.java:318)
06-18 11:13:31.066: E/AndroidRuntime(17984):    at android.view.View.requestLayout(View.java:15473)
06-18 11:13:31.066: E/AndroidRuntime(17984):    at android.view.View.requestLayout(View.java:15473)
06-18 11:13:31.066: E/AndroidRuntime(17984):    at android.widget.TextView.checkForRelayout(TextView.java:6452)
06-18 11:13:31.066: E/AndroidRuntime(17984):    at android.widget.TextView.setText(TextView.java:3696)
06-18 11:13:31.066: E/AndroidRuntime(17984):    at android.widget.TextView.setText(TextView.java:3554)
06-18 11:13:31.066: E/AndroidRuntime(17984):    at android.widget.TextView.setText(TextView.java:3529)
06-18 11:13:31.066: E/AndroidRuntime(17984):    at com.p2r.mobifin.MainActivity.dom_parser(MainActivity.java:95)
06-18 11:13:31.066: E/AndroidRuntime(17984):    at com.p2r.mobifin.MainActivity$AttemptLogin.doInBackground(MainActivity.java:165)
06-18 11:13:31.066: E/AndroidRuntime(17984):    at com.p2r.mobifin.MainActivity$AttemptLogin.doInBackground(MainActivity.java:1)
06-18 11:13:31.066: E/AndroidRuntime(17984):    at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:287)
06-18 11:13:31.066: E/AndroidRuntime(17984):    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:234)
06-18 11:13:31.066: E/AndroidRuntime(17984):    ... 4 more
06-18 11:13:31.275: W/ActivityManager(294):   Force finishing activity com.p2r.mobifin/.MainActivity
06-18 11:13:31.285: E/libEGL(36): called unimplemented OpenGL ES API
06-18 11:13:31.285: E/libEGL(36): called unimplemented OpenGL ES API
06-18 11:13:31.285: E/libEGL(36): called unimplemented OpenGL ES API
06-18 11:13:31.285: E/libEGL(36): called unimplemented OpenGL ES API
06-18 11:13:31.285: E/libEGL(36): called unimplemented OpenGL ES API
06-18 11:13:31.285: E/libEGL(36): called unimplemented OpenGL ES API
06-18 11:13:31.285: E/libEGL(36): called unimplemented OpenGL ES API
06-18 11:13:31.285: E/libEGL(36): called unimplemented OpenGL ES API
06-18 11:13:31.285: E/libEGL(36): called unimplemented OpenGL ES API
06-18 11:13:31.285: E/libEGL(36): called unimplemented OpenGL ES API
06-18 11:13:31.285: W/WindowManager(294): Failure taking screenshot for (246x410) to layer 21015
06-18 11:13:31.586: I/Choreographer(17984): Skipped 65 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
06-18 11:13:31.736: I/Choreographer(557): Skipped 44 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
06-18 11:13:31.856: I/Choreographer(294): Skipped 70 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
06-18 11:13:31.856: E/SurfaceFlinger(36): ro.sf.lcd_density must be defined as a build property
06-18 11:13:31.956: E/SurfaceFlinger(36): ro.sf.lcd_density must be defined as a build property
06-18 11:13:32.886: I/Choreographer(294): Skipped 53 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
06-18 11:13:33.976: E/WindowManager(17984): Activity com.p2r.mobifin.MainActivity has leaked window com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView{41063e50 V.E..... R.....ID 0,0-456,144} that was originally added here
06-18 11:13:33.976: E/WindowManager(17984): android.view.WindowLeaked: Activity com.p2r.mobifin.MainActivity has leaked window com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView{41063e50 V.E..... R.....ID 0,0-456,144} that was originally added here
06-18 11:13:33.976: E/WindowManager(17984):     at android.view.ViewRootImpl.<init>(ViewRootImpl.java:354)
06-18 11:13:33.976: E/WindowManager(17984):     at android.view.WindowManagerGlobal.addView(WindowManagerGlobal.java:216)
06-18 11:13:33.976: E/WindowManager(17984):     at android.view.WindowManagerImpl.addView(WindowManagerImpl.java:69)
06-18 11:13:33.976: E/WindowManager(17984):     at android.app.Dialog.show(Dialog.java:281)
06-18 11:13:33.976: E/WindowManager(17984):     at com.p2r.mobifin.MainActivity$AttemptLogin.onPreExecute(MainActivity.java:123)
06-18 11:13:33.976: E/WindowManager(17984):     at android.os.AsyncTask.executeOnExecutor(AsyncTask.java:586)
06-18 11:13:33.976: E/WindowManager(17984):     at android.os.AsyncTask.execute(AsyncTask.java:534)
06-18 11:13:33.976: E/WindowManager(17984):     at com.p2r.mobifin.MainActivity.onClick(MainActivity.java:110)
06-18 11:13:33.976: E/WindowManager(17984):     at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4204)
06-18 11:13:33.976: E/WindowManager(17984):     at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:17355)
06-18 11:13:33.976: E/WindowManager(17984):     at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:725)
06-18 11:13:33.976: E/WindowManager(17984):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
06-18 11:13:33.976: E/WindowManager(17984):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
06-18 11:13:33.976: E/WindowManager(17984):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5041)
06-18 11:13:33.976: E/WindowManager(17984):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
06-18 11:13:33.976: E/WindowManager(17984):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
06-18 11:13:33.976: E/WindowManager(17984):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:793)
06-18 11:13:33.976: E/WindowManager(17984):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:560)
06-18 11:13:33.976: E/WindowManager(17984):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
06-18 11:13:33.976: I/Choreographer(17984): Skipped 50 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
06-18 11:13:59.272: D/ExchangeService(720): Received deviceId from Email app: null
06-18 11:13:59.272: D/ExchangeService(720): !!! deviceId unknown; stopping self and retrying
06-18 11:14:04.317: D/ExchangeService(720): !!! EAS ExchangeService, onCreate
06-18 11:14:04.336: D/ExchangeService(720): !!! EAS ExchangeService, onStartCommand, startingUp = false, running = false
06-18 11:14:04.345: W/ActivityManager(294): Unable to start service Intent { act=com.android.email.ACCOUNT_INTENT } U=0: not found
06-18 11:14:04.356: D/ExchangeService(720): !!! EAS ExchangeService, onStartCommand, startingUp = true, running = false
06-18 11:14:04.356: D/ExchangeService(720): !!! Email application not found; stopping self
06-18 11:14:04.366: W/ActivityManager(294): Unable to start service Intent { act=com.android.email.ACCOUNT_INTENT } U=0: not found
06-18 11:14:04.386: E/ActivityThread(720): Service com.android.exchange.ExchangeService has leaked ServiceConnection com.android.emailcommon.service.ServiceProxy$ProxyConnection@40d045c8 that was originally bound here
06-18 11:14:04.386: E/ActivityThread(720): android.app.ServiceConnectionLeaked: Service com.android.exchange.ExchangeService has leaked ServiceConnection com.android.emailcommon.service.ServiceProxy$ProxyConnection@40d045c8 that was originally bound here
06-18 11:14:04.386: E/ActivityThread(720):  at android.app.LoadedApk$ServiceDispatcher.<init>(LoadedApk.java:969)
06-18 11:14:04.386: E/ActivityThread(720):  at android.app.LoadedApk.getServiceDispatcher(LoadedApk.java:863)
06-18 11:14:04.386: E/ActivityThread(720):  at android.app.ContextImpl.bindService(ContextImpl.java:1418)
06-18 11:14:04.386: E/ActivityThread(720):  at android.app.ContextImpl.bindService(ContextImpl.java:1407)
06-18 11:14:04.386: E/ActivityThread(720):  at android.content.ContextWrapper.bindService(ContextWrapper.java:473)
06-18 11:14:04.386: E/ActivityThread(720):  at com.android.emailcommon.service.ServiceProxy.setTask(ServiceProxy.java:157)
06-18 11:14:04.386: E/ActivityThread(720):  at com.android.emailcommon.service.ServiceProxy.setTask(ServiceProxy.java:145)
06-18 11:14:04.386: E/ActivityThread(720):  at com.android.emailcommon.service.AccountServiceProxy.getDeviceId(AccountServiceProxy.java:116)
06-18 11:14:04.386: E/ActivityThread(720):  at com.android.exchange.ExchangeService.getDeviceId(ExchangeService.java:1249)
06-18 11:14:04.386: E/ActivityThread(720):  at com.android.exchange.ExchangeService$7.run(ExchangeService.java:1856)
06-18 11:14:04.386: E/ActivityThread(720):  at com.android.emailcommon.utility.Utility$2.doInBackground(Utility.java:551)
06-18 11:14:04.386: E/ActivityThread(720):  at com.android.emailcommon.utility.Utility$2.doInBackground(Utility.java:549)
06-18 11:14:04.386: E/ActivityThread(720):  at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:287)
06-18 11:14:04.386: E/ActivityThread(720):  at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:234)
06-18 11:14:04.386: E/ActivityThread(720):  at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1080)
06-18 11:14:04.386: E/ActivityThread(720):  at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:573)
06-18 11:14:04.386: E/ActivityThread(720):  at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:856)
06-18 11:14:04.386: E/StrictMode(720): null
06-18 11:14:04.386: E/StrictMode(720): android.app.ServiceConnectionLeaked: Service com.android.exchange.ExchangeService has leaked ServiceConnection com.android.emailcommon.service.ServiceProxy$ProxyConnection@40d045c8 that was originally bound here
06-18 11:14:04.386: E/StrictMode(720):  at android.app.LoadedApk$ServiceDispatcher.<init>(LoadedApk.java:969)
06-18 11:14:04.386: E/StrictMode(720):  at android.app.LoadedApk.getServiceDispatcher(LoadedApk.java:863)
06-18 11:14:04.386: E/StrictMode(720):  at android.app.ContextImpl.bindService(ContextImpl.java:1418)
06-18 11:14:04.386: E/StrictMode(720):  at android.app.ContextImpl.bindService(ContextImpl.java:1407)
06-18 11:14:04.386: E/StrictMode(720):  at android.content.ContextWrapper.bindService(ContextWrapper.java:473)
06-18 11:14:04.386: E/StrictMode(720):  at com.android.emailcommon.service.ServiceProxy.setTask(ServiceProxy.java:157)
06-18 11:14:04.386: E/StrictMode(720):  at com.android.emailcommon.service.ServiceProxy.setTask(ServiceProxy.java:145)
06-18 11:14:04.386: E/StrictMode(720):  at com.android.emailcommon.service.AccountServiceProxy.getDeviceId(AccountServiceProxy.java:116)
06-18 11:14:04.386: E/StrictMode(720):  at com.android.exchange.ExchangeService.getDeviceId(ExchangeService.java:1249)
06-18 11:14:04.386: E/StrictMode(720):  at com.android.exchange.ExchangeService$7.run(ExchangeService.java:1856)
06-18 11:14:04.386: E/StrictMode(720):  at com.android.emailcommon.utility.Utility$2.doInBackground(Utility.java:551)
06-18 11:14:04.386: E/StrictMode(720):  at com.android.emailcommon.utility.Utility$2.doInBackground(Utility.java:549)
06-18 11:14:04.386: E/StrictMode(720):  at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:287)
06-18 11:14:04.386: E/StrictMode(720):  at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:234)
06-18 11:14:04.386: E/StrictMode(720):  at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1080)
06-18 11:14:04.386: E/StrictMode(720):  at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:573)
06-18 11:14:04.386: E/StrictMode(720):  at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:856)
06-18 11:14:04.386: W/ActivityManager(294): Unbind failed: could not find connection for android.os.BinderProxy@412abcd0
06-18 11:14:04.406: E/ActivityThread(720): Service com.android.exchange.ExchangeService has leaked ServiceConnection com.android.emailcommon.service.ServiceProxy$ProxyConnection@40d0dbc8 that was originally bound here
06-18 11:14:04.406: E/ActivityThread(720): android.app.ServiceConnectionLeaked: Service com.android.exchange.ExchangeService has leaked ServiceConnection com.android.emailcommon.service.ServiceProxy$ProxyConnection@40d0dbc8 that was originally bound here
06-18 11:14:04.406: E/ActivityThread(720):  at android.app.LoadedApk$ServiceDispatcher.<init>(LoadedApk.java:969)
06-18 11:14:04.406: E/ActivityThread(720):  at android.app.LoadedApk.getServiceDispatcher(LoadedApk.java:863)
06-18 11:14:04.406: E/ActivityThread(720):  at android.app.ContextImpl.bindService(ContextImpl.java:1418)
06-18 11:14:04.406: E/ActivityThread(720):  at android.app.ContextImpl.bindService(ContextImpl.java:1407)
06-18 11:14:04.406: E/ActivityThread(720):  at android.content.ContextWrapper.bindService(ContextWrapper.java:473)
06-18 11:14:04.406: E/ActivityThread(720):  at com.android.emailcommon.service.ServiceProxy.setTask(ServiceProxy.java:157)
06-18 11:14:04.406: E/ActivityThread(720):  at com.android.emailcommon.service.ServiceProxy.setTask(ServiceProxy.java:145)
06-18 11:14:04.406: E/ActivityThread(720):  at com.android.emailcommon.service.ServiceProxy.test(ServiceProxy.java:191)
06-18 11:14:04.406: E/ActivityThread(720):  at com.android.exchange.ExchangeService$7.run(ExchangeService.java:1850)
06-18 11:14:04.406: E/ActivityThread(720):  at com.android.emailcommon.utility.Utility$2.doInBackground(Utility.java:551)
06-18 11:14:04.406: E/ActivityThread(720):  at com.android.emailcommon.utility.Utility$2.doInBackground(Utility.java:549)
06-18 11:14:04.406: E/ActivityThread(720):  at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:287)
06-18 11:14:04.406: E/ActivityThread(720):  at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:234)
06-18 11:14:04.406: E/ActivityThread(720):  at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1080)
06-18 11:14:04.406: E/ActivityThread(720):  at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:573)
06-18 11:14:04.406: E/ActivityThread(720):  at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:856)
06-18 11:14:04.406: E/StrictMode(720): null
06-18 11:14:04.406: E/StrictMode(720): android.app.ServiceConnectionLeaked: Service com.android.exchange.ExchangeService has leaked ServiceConnection com.android.emailcommon.service.ServiceProxy$ProxyConnection@40d0dbc8 that was originally bound here
06-18 11:14:04.406: E/StrictMode(720):  at android.app.LoadedApk$ServiceDispatcher.<init>(LoadedApk.java:969)
06-18 11:14:04.406: E/StrictMode(720):  at android.app.LoadedApk.getServiceDispatcher(LoadedApk.java:863)
06-18 11:14:04.406: E/StrictMode(720):  at android.app.ContextImpl.bindService(ContextImpl.java:1418)
06-18 11:14:04.406: E/StrictMode(720):  at android.app.ContextImpl.bindService(ContextImpl.java:1407)
06-18 11:14:04.406: E/StrictMode(720):  at android.content.ContextWrapper.bindService(ContextWrapper.java:473)
06-18 11:14:04.406: E/StrictMode(720):  at com.android.emailcommon.service.ServiceProxy.setTask(ServiceProxy.java:157)
06-18 11:14:04.406: E/StrictMode(720):  at com.android.emailcommon.service.ServiceProxy.setTask(ServiceProxy.java:145)
06-18 11:14:04.406: E/StrictMode(720):  at com.android.emailcommon.service.ServiceProxy.test(ServiceProxy.java:191)
06-18 11:14:04.406: E/StrictMode(720):  at com.android.exchange.ExchangeService$7.run(ExchangeService.java:1850)
06-18 11:14:04.406: E/StrictMode(720):  at com.android.emailcommon.utility.Utility$2.doInBackground(Utility.java:551)
06-18 11:14:04.406: E/StrictMode(720):  at com.android.emailcommon.utility.Utility$2.doInBackground(Utility.java:549)
06-18 11:14:04.406: E/StrictMode(720):  at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:287)
06-18 11:14:04.406: E/StrictMode(720):  at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:234)
06-18 11:14:04.406: E/StrictMode(720):  at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1080)
06-18 11:14:04.406: E/StrictMode(720):  at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:573)
06-18 11:14:04.406: E/StrictMode(720):  at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:856)
06-18 11:14:04.416: W/ActivityManager(294): Unbind failed: could not find connection for android.os.BinderProxy@413e8d38
06-18 11:14:10.936: I/Process(17984): Sending signal. PID: 17984 SIG: 9
06-18 11:14:10.956: I/ActivityManager(294): Process com.p2r.mobifin (pid 17984) has died.
06-18 11:14:11.056: W/InputMethodManagerService(294): Got RemoteException sending setActive(false) notification to pid 17984 uid 10050
```

Comment: post your logcat traces

Comment: a) is dom_parser(); a defined method?
b) I don't think this is possible `response_xml.setText("Incorrect Login!");`

Comment: a) yes, dom_parser(); is a defined method used to parse the xml! b) response_xml is a TextBox and i'm setting a message in the TextBox

Comment: @ProkashSarkar Please post the method dom_parser() and getValue() from MainActivity. From the logcat, your error is a NullPointerExecption from a call to getValue(), which is made from dom_parser().  Difficult to say what is wrong with out seeing the code where the NullPointerException is thrown.

Comment: @Flynn81 i've update my post with the methods you wanted to see. Please check it out!

Comment: What is the data type of responseXML?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you need to modify `getValue()` as I did below.  The parameter `element` to that method should be a member node.  Calling `getElementsByTagName()` will return descendents, which should be the tags you are trying to parse.  Calling getChildNodes() was attempting to find the tag inside of those tags, which wouldn't exist.

Instead `element.getElementsByTagName(tag).item(0)` should return the node matching the tag you are trying to find.

```
private static String getValue(String tag, Element element) {
    Node node = element.getElementsByTagName(tag).item(0);
    return node.getNodeValue();
}
```

Also, please note, per the documentation for `Node`, getValue() may still return null for items like `<username/>` (from your sample xml).

https://developer.android.com/reference/org/w3c/dom/Node.html

Comment: thanks a lot for the reply, its giving an error if i remove .getChildNodes() from NodeList nodes = element.getElementsByTagName(tag).item(0).getChildNodes(); (cannot convert from node to NodeList)

Comment: sounds like it can't find the tag, I'd try debugging it to see what element really is, and what descendants it has, sorry